# How to program an nRFL01 RF module that is connected to a pc via a USB to UART/TTL adapter?

Tags: usb, nrf24l01+, wireless, uart, rf

In a few of my previous questions I was told that the nRF24L01 RF Module can be connected to a pc using a USB to UART/TTL adapter. After a bit of research I understand that one way to use it is to connect it to an arduino- and then to use certain dedicated libraries like RF24.h, and nRF24L01.h to send and receive data. Though I've not been able to find any tutorial outlining the procedure for programming the nRF24L01 once its been connected to the pc. 
  How do I send and receive data using my pc-interface? What software do I write and how do I write it?

Comment: No, it needs a USB to SPI interface, not USB to UART interface. That's the FT2232 not the FT232 (confusing I know).

Comment: @Majenko - actually, I believe you can do SPI with the FT232H and possibly even very slowly the everyday FT232RL.  But you are right that this is not UART functionality but a different operating mode and its corresponding host side API, and also the FT2232H/FT44232H are much better at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: whatever software you use on the remote end (rf24.h for example) you have to re-write on the PC using whatever language you can interface to the FT2232 with. That means having intimate knowledge of:

1. The USB to SPI adapter you choose (NOT USB TO UART!)
2. The low-level control and interfacing of the nRF24L01+ chip
3. The exact protocol used by your chosen Arduino library.

That's a lot of understanding which (by the level of your questions) is most likely way outside your area of ability.

If you equate time to money then the cost of doing what you want to do is far higher than just using a small Arduino to act as an intelligent interface between your PC and your chosen wireless system. You can discount points 2 and 3 above since they have already been done for you by the Arduino libraries and tutorials. Point 1 becomes considerably easier since you are then just talking to an Arduino using a protocol which you yourself have come up with.

So do yourself (and us) a favour and come to your senses and just plug the nRF24L01+ into an Arduino then plug the Arduino into your PC and program the Arduino to do the RF communications according to commands and instructions you send to your sketch from the PC.